# Override keypress method in lwuit

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

How to override keypressed method  form in lwuit?
if suppose user press numeric 1 from keypad how can I know that user has pressed 1?
In canvas we just need to handle keypressed method. but in lwuit how to handle this method.
and which listener I have to implements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keypressed is method in interface so you always override that methos in class

see [this example](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/06/customizing-lwuits-focus-behavior.html)

if you dont khow exact key code then print key code in

```
public void keyPressed(keyCode){
System.out.println(keyCode);
}
```

run your program, press "1" and see output

Comment: in which component you have registered listener? can i see code?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the form's keyPressed/Releaseed methods (normally you should override release!). Every focusable component has these methods as well and will receive the keyPressed/Released calls when it has focus so you can override them in component as well.
The keycode you will receive for numeric/character keys is the actual character (e.g. for your case '1').

You can register global listeners for the form using key listener/game listener in the form (addKeyListener, addGameKeyListener).

Notice that LWUIT has a "game key" concept for navigation/action buttons since the values for these buttons often differ between platforms.